# Order of non-blocking operations in MPI

Tags: mpi, mpich

I have some code where I move data around using MPI non-blocking operations. What I require is that the operations follow an order, that I specify, but I'm not sure if that's happening.

For example, the operations look like this:

```
MPI_Rget(buffer, source, &req[0]); // A   
MPI_Ibarrier(&req[1]); // B    
MPI_Rput(dest, buffer, &req[2]); // C  
MPI_Ibarrier(&req[3]); // D  
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    MPI_Wait(&req[i]);
```

I need operation A to be guaranteed to complete before C, so that the buffer has the data I "get" before I "put" it.
I also need a guarantee that operation C isn't started by any process until all processes finish operation A, which I hoped would be provided by operation B.

I was wondering whether this code was correct, and if not, what I could do to provide the ordering guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

1. A barrier is not enough synchronization for request-based operations: if one needs to come after the other, you need a `MPI_Waitwhatever` call for the request of the first
2. `Rget` is a one-sided call and only valid in a passive target epoch. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: This doc [1] seems to indicate that non-blocking operations are ordered.    
Is it that Rget/Rput don't count as non-blocking operations?

[1] https://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node65.htm#Node65

Comment: Let's get some basics straight. Please answer point 2 in my edited answer.

Comment: point to point operations are ordered, one sided are not. please post a full [mcve] so we can understand whether you are using passive or active targets.